# How to load only few properties from entity?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4.0 and I have created 3 entities from DB.

In DB, I have the following tables Employee,Contact,Department.

Employee Table -> EmployeeID,Name,Designation

ContactTable -> ContactID,Address,CellNo,EMployeeID(FK)

Department Table -> DepartmentID,Name,EmployeeID(FK)

After converting into entities from DB, I get following entities

EmployeeObject ->
EmployeeID,Name,Designation,Contact(Another Entity),Department(Another Entity).

Till this its ok, now I want to bind the employees to data grid its also work fine...
I use below code to bind employees to record ...

code working perfectly, now issue is when I see the data into grid , Two extra column comes
into grid, Contacts and Departments.

Please see the image

[Click  here to see screenshot of result grid](https://picasaweb.google.com/111036459721552617166/July142012#5764920127191591394)

[Entity Model Pic](https://picasaweb.google.com/111036459721552617166/July14201202#5764920856118780386)

I want to bind only records which are into employee table not the object which are in 
entity (Contacts and Department.)

Comment: Sorry, that page was not found.

Comment: You need to search for documentation or examples how to bind only a few selected properties of an object to a winforms data grid. You are probably using some "AutoGenerateColumns" setting of the grid (maybe that's a default setting) that just binds every property to a grid columns. The question has nothing to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: Nop, I am talking lazy loading, When I load employee contacts and department also load. how to overcome from it ?

Comment: Turn off lazy loading for your operation: `myObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`. But you will still have the two columns in the grid, they just will be empty.